# willcascadeondelete in .netMVC4 is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first

I am creating .net MVC4 application. i have two entitites named group and groupmembers. group has a one to many relations with groupmembers.
Here are my classes

```
public class Group
  { 
    public int GroupId{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<GroupMember> Members { get; set; }
  }

public class GroupMember
{
  public int GroupMemberId { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    }
```

on the model side i am using the code

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<GroupMember>()
          .HasRequired(e => e.Group)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.GroupId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

My problem is while deleting the group the members of the group is not getting deleted.Can any one please give me a solution

Comment: What is GroupUser? Your ModelBuilder is configuring that but you aren't showing us the entity. You have GroupMember and Group

Comment: have you tried   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); ??

Answer (score -1):

The WillCascadeOnDelete() tells EF that the database will perform the delete. EF does not perform the cascade, so you need to change your tables to add the delete.

You can do this in SSMS designer by opening the relationship selecting Delete for Cascade Action, or you can do it in T-SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.GroupMember DROP CONSTRAINT fkName
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.GroupMember ADD CONSTRAINT
fkName FOREIGN KEY (GroupId) 
REFERENCES dbo.Group (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```